# Where would I find information about Sales Tax in New Jersey about tutoring?

Tags: tax-law

Is there a document or New Jersey official page where I could find information about sales tax pertaining to conducting tutoring services in New Jersey? I am using a Stripe Payment system and it doesn't take out Sales Tax and it concerns me because I can't seem to find anything or simply don't know where to search to find such information.

Answer (score 3):

[This document](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/pubs/sales/su4.pdf) explains what is taxable vs. exempt, and also explains how to get more definitive answers (email, call, office visit).